# Language Manager getCurrentLanguage returns default language instead

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I am creating a multilingual D8 site, which 3 languages enabled.

In trying to display the currently active language, the snippet

```
$lang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getName();
```

always returns the default language ( English ) even though the UI has switched to one of the alternative languages. The above line is called from the `mytheme.theme` file in `hook_preprocess_page`.

In the language switcher block, the correct language is getting the session-active is-active classes.

When referencing the documentation for D8.5 in the above method, in the code shown it very much shows like this is what the function does:

```
public function getCurrentLanguage($type = LanguageInterface::TYPE_INTERFACE) 
{
  return $this
    ->getDefaultLanguage();
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Is there another way to get the current active language?

Comment: What are your language detection/selection settings for both content and interface? `getCurrentLanguage` will return the current interface (not content) language unless you pass it `LanguageInterface::TYPE_CONTENT`, and depending on your settings, interface language might not be being detected the same way as content language

Answer (score 2):

The method you've quoted is the default code for single language sites. For multilingual sites the default LanguageManager is replaced with [`ConfigurableLanguageManager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21language%21src%21ConfigurableLanguageManager.php/class/ConfigurableLanguageManager/8.6.x) and the method is overridden wtih this content:

*ConfigurableLanguageManager::getCurrentLanguage:*

```
public function getCurrentLanguage($type = LanguageInterface::TYPE_INTERFACE) {
  if (!isset($this->negotiatedLanguages[$type])) {

    // Ensure we have a valid value for this language type.
    $this->negotiatedLanguages[$type] = $this
      ->getDefaultLanguage();
    if ($this->negotiator && $this
      ->isMultilingual()) {
      if (!$this->initializing) {
        $this->initializing = TRUE;
        $negotiation = $this->negotiator
          ->initializeType($type);
        $this->negotiatedLanguages[$type] = reset($negotiation);
        $this->negotiatedMethods[$type] = key($negotiation);
        $this->initializing = FALSE;
      }
      elseif ($type == LanguageInterface::TYPE_INTERFACE) {
        return new Language([
          'id' => LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_SYSTEM,
        ]);
      }
    }
  }
  return $this->negotiatedLanguages[$type];
}
```

Then the result depends on the language negotiators you have configured in language detection, see [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/268291/language-manager-getcurrentlanguage-returns-default-language-instead#comment329165_268291) from @Clive.